# Collator compares strings weird

Tags: java, sorting

I have a collection of strings and need to sort it. I'm using the Collator.
But the output is weird.

```
final Collator collator = Collator.getInstance(Locale.US);

List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();

data.add("1Z5800701_AB");
data.add("1Z5800701_AC");
data.add("1Z5800701-A");
data.add("1Z5800701 A");
data.add("1Z5800701B");
data.add("1Z5800701A");
data.add("1Z5800701 - A");

Collections.sort(data, new Comparator<String>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        return collator.compare(o1, o2);
    }
});

for (String s : data) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

And the output is:

```
1Z5800701_AB
1Z5800701_AC
1Z5800701A
1Z5800701 A
1Z5800701 - A
1Z5800701-A
1Z5800701B
```

The last one string '1Z5800701B' should be after '1Z5800701A'. What am I missing here?

Comment: Why would "1Z5800701A" come after "1Z5800701B"?

Comment: I don't say that. I say 1Z5800701B should go after 1Z5800701A,because B is alphabetically after A, doesn't it?

Comment: Remember that Collator `performs locale-sensitive String comparison`. So it's not exactly char by char comparisons but language specific comparisons.

Comment: I know that, but why is 1Z5800701B the last one in US locale?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a matter of the locale used, you can reproduce the same behavior in the bash shell with `LC_ALL=en_US sort`. The point is that the "word separators" are treated differently from "word characters" in this locale (i.e. you can't always say that character X sorts before or after character B - it depends on context). The result is if you have `1Z5800701 <optional separators> A`, it sorts before `1Z5800701 <optional separators> B`, that's why `1Z5800701B` comes after all combinations where the `A` comes after the digits, optionally separated by "separators". You can also see some more examples of "not obvious" orderings in [this Wikipedia articles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphabetical_order)

Comment: You basically say - it's locale sensitive, it's a fact. But I would like to know the rule. Why is the order like the above?

Comment: @Behnil On my system, `en_US` locale inherits all collation rules from the file `/usr/share/i18n/locales/iso14651_t1_common` which is a 345 kB-long textual description of the collation rules. Have a look at the [Unicode Collation Algorithm](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr10/) if you can stand it. It's terribly complex. There are two main [ways of handling multiword strings when sorting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphabetical_order#Treatment_of_multiword_strings) and here the approach was chosen in which word boundaries are not relevant.

Comment: I accept your answer although I'm not fully satisfied with it. The fact that between 1Z5800701A and 1Z5800701B are another strings is obscure. The Collator is useless then.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a bug it's a feature :)

`java.text.Collator` has only one default implementation; `RuleBasedCollator`, and it ignores whites spaces.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/RuleBasedCollator.html

Just check the class of your Collator

```
final Collator collator = Collator.getInstance(Locale.US);
System.out.println(collator.getClass().getName());
```

Comment: Even if you are right and it ignores whitespaces, then the order 1Z5800701A,
1Z5800701A,
1Z5800701-A,
1Z5800701-A,
1Z5800701B still doesn't make sense to me. I can't see there any rule.

Comment: RuleBasedCollator.getRules()