# Java collation ignores space

Tags: java, collation

I became recently aware, that Java Collation seems to ignore spaces.

I have a list of the following terms:

```
Amman Jost 
Ammann Heinrich 
Ammanner Josef 
Bär Walter 
Bare Werner 
Barr Burt 
Barraud Maurice
```

The order above reflects the desired ordering for Germany, i.e. taking space into acount.
However, Java Collation using

```
Collator collator = Collator.getInstance(Locale.GERMANY);
Collections.sort(values, collator);
```

gives me the following order:

```
Amman Jost
Ammanner Josef
Ammann Heinrich
Bare Werner
Barraud Maurice
Barr Burt
Bär Walter
```

The result above is actually not what I have expected, since spaces are not taken into account (looks like the case described here: [Wikipedia Alphabetical order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphabetical_order#Treatment_of_multiword_strings)).

Does this mean, that Java Collation is not usable for such use case or am I doing something wrong here? Is there a way to make Java Collation space aware?

I would be glad for any comments or recommendations.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15230339/collator-compares-strings-weird

Answer (score 12):

You can customize the collation. Try looking at the source code to see how the Collator for German locale is built, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13531475/587365).

Then adapt it to your needs. The [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/rule.html) gives a starting point. But no need to do all the work, someone else already has done it: see this [blog post dealing with the exact same problem for Czech](http://jan.baresovi.cz/dr/en/java-collator-spaces).

The essence of the solution linked above is:

```
String rules = ((RuleBasedCollator) Collator.getInstance(Locale.GERMANY)).getRules();
RuleBasedCollator correctedCollator 
    = new RuleBasedCollator(rules.replaceAll("<'\u005f'", "<' '<'\u005f'"));
```

This adds a rule for the space character just before the rule for underscore.

I confess I haven't tested this personally.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and useful links. 
Bigger issue is that for a web based application which is supposed to collate by a users locale, one would need to enhance potentially many locales.

Comment: Then you should write it yourself: see if my proposition below can help

Comment: @jhasenbe Yes it's not satisfactory. You could probably hack something to perform the same change on any locale with similar rules, but it would be a hack

Answer (score -1):

If you cannot modify the locale for some reasons, then I would propose that you write everything by yourself. Here are some ideas, though this code is not complete and does not work:

- Instead of having a list of Strings, create your own objects, implementing comparable:

  ```
  public class myString implements Comparable<myString> {
      private String name;

      public myString(String name) {
         this.name = name;
      }
  }
  ```
- Then you will need to implement (see an example [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/))

  ```
  public int compareTo(myString compareMyString) {
      ...
  }
  ```
- Now comes the trickier part:

  - In order to compare your strings, you will need to split them (this will result in an array of Strings). For instance:

    ```
    // Original String
    "Barr Burt"

    // Splitted String
    [0]: "Barr"
    [1]: "Burt"
    ```
  - You will need to compare the words one after the other. Create a function doing something like this (This is a pseudo code: "this.words[i]" calls the i-th word of "this.name")

    ```
    public int compareWords(myString compareMyString, int i)
    {
        if (this.words[i] < compareMyString.words[i])
            return -1; // "this" should come before "compareMyString"

        if (this.words[i] > compareMyString.words[i])
            return 1; // "this" should come after "compareMyString"

        if (this.words[i] == compareMyString.words[i])
            return compareWords(i+1);
    }
    ```
  - And then `compareTo`:

    ```
    public int compareTo(myString compareMyString) {
        return compareWords(compareMyString, 0);
    }
    ```