# Java case insensitive localized ordering

Tags: java, sorting

I have set of hyphenated string sets. That I want to sort considering the locale.

```
List<String> words = Arrays.asList("App - Small", "Apple", "App - Big");

Collator collator = Collator.getInstance(new Locale("en"));

// Sort Method 1            
Collections.sort(words, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
System.out.println(words.toString());

// Sort Method 2        
collator.setStrength(Collator.PRIMARY);
Collections.sort(words, collator);
System.out.println(words.toString());
```

### Result

```
String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER

[App - Big, App - Small, Apple]  

Collator.PRIMARY

[App - Big, Apple, App - Small]
```

Though the Collator.PRIMARY is supposed to do a case-insensitive sorting there is difference between the order using the above two methods. How can I achieve locale based case-insensitive sort order that works with hyphen.

[App - Big, App - Small, Apple] - Expected sort order

Comment: I am using TreeMap so I wrote that initially. Edited to remove that from the subject. Regarding, the sort order that is the expected output from my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the quote from the API.

It does not only depend on the strength but also other things. Enclose hyphen('-') between single quotes and you will get the desired output ''

> The definitions of the rule elements is as follows:
>
> - Text-Argument: A text-argument is any sequence of characters, excluding special characters (that is, common whitespace characters [0009-000D, 0020] and rule syntax characters [0021-002F, 003A-0040, 005B-0060, 007B-007E]). If those characters are desired, you can put them in single quotes (e.g. ampersand => '&'). Note that unquoted white space characters are ignored; e.g. b c is treated as bc.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/RuleBasedCollator.html#compare(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)

Answer (score 2):

There is no case sensitivity issue involved. The collator ignores spaces and hyphens so, since all strings start with “App”, the significant letters are “`S`”, “`l`”, and “`B`” in your example and the resulting order “`B`” “`L`” “`S`” is correct.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16567287/java-collation-ignores-space for more info.